SQL query to get the names of the partitions which are detached from the parent table in postgres?
I used pg_partman to create and drop partitions from my 2 postgres tables. Since there existed a foreign key relations among the tables, I couldn't drop the tables using partman(does not allow).
However, I was able to detach the older partitioned tables(data older than 30 days) from the parent table. Now, in order to clean these tables, I need to get the names of the detached tables.
What sql query would help me achieve this ?

Since those tables are no longer attached to the partition parent, you need another way to identify them. Typically, you have naming pattern for partitions ...

Can we use pg_inherits and pg_class tables ?

Entries in those system catalogs are updated to look like regular tables. I don't know of anything still pointing to their partition past.

@ErwinBrandstetter The below query works but I want this to be reviewed and understand its correctness. Please have a look. The parent table's name is user_session_data :  SELECT relname FROM pg_class c LEFT JOIN pg_inherits i ON c.oid = i.inhrelid WHERE i.inhrelid IS NULL AND relkind = 'r' AND relname LIKE 'user_session_data_%';

So do you have your answer?

Those tables are no longer attached to the partition parent, you need another way to identify them. Your comment indicates the naming pattern 'user_session_data_%'.
This returns all tables matching that pattern that are not partitions (any more):
SELECT relnamespace::regnamespace::text AS schema_name, relname AS table_name
FROM   pg_class c
WHERE  NOT relispartition  -- !
AND    relkind = 'r'
AND    relname LIKE 'user_session_data_%';  -- naming pattern for partitions

No need to join to pg_inherits. While Postgres maintains additional meta data for partitions (and legacy inheritance) there, looking at the flag pg_class.relispartition is simpler and more to the point. It's defined NOT NULL, so NOT relispartition can't fail for null values.
I also output the schema name to avoid possible confusion with other schemas.
Alternatively, filter for the schema instead. Like:
...
AND   relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace  -- your schema name here

